# In jQuery AJAX request where the callback paramer comes from?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In a website when submitting a search, a GET request is made, e.g. `https://a.somesite.com/file.php?callback=jQuery1111076252760730124087_1466446816179&v=abc&f=mp3&_=1466446816180`

I want to faciliate the request in C# without dealing with JS. But in order to be as accurate as possible I want to figure out where the callback parameter comes from. I don't need it for anything, just want to generate a legit looking one, and generally, where does the callback value come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback parameter may be related to a **JSONP** call. 
You can check about JSONP at https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/